# A rigged model to practice on

Tags: modeling

Where do I get a rigged model to learn with? Am I missing that it's already in one of the menus?  I have imported a bvh file from a mocap. I want to place the bones in a model to get a feel for what it is I am caputring.

Comment: Welcome to Blender StackExchange! Questions like this are usually considered as off-topic as requests for resources aren't directly connected with Blender. That being said, there is this post (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) contains a lot of useful links to resources. The models link/answer will be what you are looking for. If you are just looking for a rig, the rigify addon contains a few rig presets, but they aren't connected to any models.

Comment: I'll just add that this is exactly what the [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org) has been created for, big plus is you'll be helping Blender development.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [MakeHuman](http://makehuman.org) this allows you to create and customise a human model and add a rig. The model (with rig) can then be exported in a format that can then be imported into Blender.

Comment: If you want to stay in Blender and just use an add on you can always use ManuelBastioniLAB http://www.manuelbastioni.com/manuellab.php